# How to pronounce “ch” and “j” sounds at the end of the syllable?

Tags: pronunciation

I’m confused with these two sounds when they are at the end of the syllable. I know that “ch” and “j” are comprised of two sound: **tsh** and **dzh** respectively. So I think words like *teach* and *page* are pronounced like this: **teat** and **pad** in the first part without releasing the air (stop sound). But that would sound like the word “teat” and “paid”. I’m not sure about it even when I listen carefully to the pronunciation of the words. And here’s my recording: [teach](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11s2lg1CSS10bhehSn4u5A3A8KeFqY8Ye) and [page](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e4ewxs14Rh9Y6Jve9ImjI7T6p41sEaxt)

In the recording I used with **t** and **d** in the first pair and the second pair is what I have always used.

Which is correct?

And if possible could you give pronunciations of the word slowly?

Answer (score 2):

In teach, you're correctly making the ch sound, and the whole word sounds very good. But for page, you're also making the ch sound, but you need to make the j sound.

How do you say other words containing j?

Keep in mind, a j sound at the end of a word is the same as a j sound at the beginning of a word; "page" ends with the same sound that "gem" and "joy" start with.

The main difference between the ch and j (or soft g) sounds are that the ch is unvoiced, and the j is voiced. When you're making the ch sound, your vocal chords don't hum. To make the j sound, put your tongue in the same place but a little softer, and hum your vocal chords. Here's more about voiced and unvoiced sounds: https://jonathansamericanenglish.com/2017/11/09/voiced-and-unvoiced-sounds/

Comment: To elaborate: You've figured out that the /ch/ and the /j/ noises are almost like their own syllables (even though a native speaker would probably say that "teach" and "page" were one-syllable words). You have the hissing noise of the /ch/ down, but try to pronounce "page" slowly as a two-syllable "paid-juh" and then speed it up and shorten the "uh" noise as much as you can. You need to continue to use voice just a little longer through the word so that the /j/ phoneme is recognizable, without going too long to make too much of an "uh" noise.

Answer (score 0):

The place of articulation of both phonemes is the same. What makes them different is sonority (vibration of the vocal chords), *ch* is voiceless and *j* voiced. English has two affricate phonemes, /t͡ʃ/ and /d͡ʒ/, often spelled ⟨ch⟩ and ⟨j⟩, respectively.

Comment: Answers on Stack Exchange aren't designed to be replies to other answers — they're answers to the *question* — so I've edited this to hopefully make it clearer, but please double-check to make sure it's answering the question as squarely as possible